# Manipulating data in struct format ends up weird

Tags: c++, depth-first-search

So I am working on a maze generator program as a dfs practice.

```
struct Point{
    Point *left,*right,*up,*down;
    int x,y;
    bool visited;
    Point(int n,int m)
        :x(n),y(m),visited(false),left(NULL),right(NULL),up(NULL),down(NULL)
    {}
};
```

and I have used a for loop to initialize a vector of vector of Point,
each with a unique address and the visited value assigned as false.

```
    vector<vector<Point*> > board;
        for(i=0;i<row;i++){
            for(j=0;j<col;j++){
                Point *temppt=new Point(j,i);
                tempv.push_back(temppt);
            }
            board.push_back(tempv);
        }
        for(i=0;i<row;i++){
            for(j=0;j<col;j++){
                if(i!=0)board[i][j]->up=board[i-1][j];
                if(i!=row-1)board[i][j]->down=board[i+1][j];
                if(j!=0)board[i][j]->left=board[i][j-1];
                if(j!=col-1)board[i][j]->right=board[i][j+1];
            }
        }
```

However, something weird happens when I manipulate them during a dfs search...

whenever I execute this segment of code

```
            board[now->y][now->x]->visited=true;
```

each of the first value of the vector of board (board[x][0]) are also changed to true, as a checked it with this for loop.

```
        for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
                cout<<board[i][j]->visited;
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
```

What should I do to manipulate the points one of one instead of column by column

The full dfs function:

```
    void dfs(Point* now,Point* prev,int cnt){
        int dir,back;
        if(now->visited!=true){
            cnt++;
            if(prev!=NULL){
                if(prev->up==now){
                    hwall[now->x][now->y]=false;
                }
                else if(prev->down==now){
                    hwall[prev->x][prev->y]=false;
                }
                else if(prev->right==now){
                    vwall[prev->y][prev->x]=false;
                }
                else vwall[now->y][now->x]=false;
            }
            board[now->y][now->x]->visited=true;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
                cout<<board[i][j]->visited;
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
        if(cnt<row*col){
            back=rand()%10;
            vector<Point*> temp;
            if(back<5){
                A:;
                if(now->up!=NULL)temp.push_back(now->up);
                if(now->right!=NULL)temp.push_back(now->right);
                if(now->down!=NULL)temp.push_back(now->down);
                if(now->left!=NULL)temp.push_back(now->left);
                dfs(temp[rand()%temp.size()],now,cnt);
            }
            else{
                if(now->up!=NULL&&now->up->visited!=true)temp.push_back(now->up);
                if(now->right!=NULL&&now->right->visited!=true)temp.push_back(now->right);
                if(now->down!=NULL&&now->down->visited!=true)temp.push_back(now->down);
                if(now->left!=NULL&&now->left->visited!=true)temp.push_back(now->left);
                if(temp.size()==0)goto A;
                dfs(temp[rand()%temp.size()],now,cnt);
            }
        }
    }
```

The full constructor:

```
Maze(int n,int m):row(n),col(m){
        int i,j;
        vector<Point*> tempv;
        for(i=0;i<row;i++)vwall.push_back(vector<bool>(col-1,true));
        for(i=0;i<col;i++)hwall.push_back(vector<bool>(row-1,true));
        for(i=0;i<row;i++){
            for(j=0;j<col;j++){
                Point *temppt=new Point(j,i);
                tempv.push_back(temppt);
            }
            board.push_back(tempv);
        }
        for(i=0;i<row;i++){
            for(j=0;j<col;j++){
                if(i!=0)board[i][j]->up=board[i-1][j];
                if(i!=row-1)board[i][j]->down=board[i+1][j];
                if(j!=0)board[i][j]->left=board[i][j-1];
                if(j!=col-1)board[i][j]->right=board[i][j+1];
            }
        }
        dfs(board[0][0],NULL,0);
    }
```

Comment: Can you put the completed code snippet when calling `board[now->y][now->x]->visited=true;`? And what is `tempv` declaration ?

Comment: Just added it, thanks for your attention :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't clearing tempv after you push it back into board.  So each entry of board is receiving an extended copy of tempv.  (Specifically, the first `col` entries will be identical in each row.)

Just call `tempv.clear()` right after `board.push_back(tempv)`, so that each row starts with an empty vector.

Comment: Whoops! That was a careless move of me. Now the code runs fine with the adjustment, thanks for the help! :D

Comment: @haleyk happydave would surely be glad to get his answer selected by you as the best answer :-)